# ModelForm data to JSON String

Tags: python, json, django

I'm writing a model form which on save needs to build the inputted data into a JSON string to be sent of to requests as a payload.

I've tried a few different ways, none of which seem to work.  Yet when using the API in terminal, I can get it to work fine when I manually type up the JSON String.

```
{
    "factory_id":"XXXX-YYYYY",
    "name":"Dance Room",
    "latitude":XX.XXXXXX,
    "longitude":YY.YYYYYY,
    "config_id":abcd,
    "visibility": "private"
}
```

The above is the Request JSON that must be sent, however only factory_id, name and visibility are required.

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = (
            'name',
            'factory_id',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'visible',
            'config_id',
        )
```

I need to be able to pass that data into the payload arg of my API wrapper, but I just get 500 errors from the API when doing it this way.

What is the best way to go about building the JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one myself. It might not be the prettiest way, but it sure darn worked.

```
payload = {}
payload['factory_id'] = "XXXX-YYYYY"
payload['name'] = "Dance Room"
payload['latitude'] = XX.XXXXXX
payload['longitude'] = YY.YYYYYY
payload['config_id'] = abcd
payload['visibility'] = "private"

data = json.dumps(payload)
```

This then gave me a nice perfect JSON string ready to send for my API Wrapper.